# Stripping out newline characters from input JSON string when using COPY Command in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-16

I have a set of code that is importing a JSON file provided into a temp table as follows:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
    CREATE TEMP  table tmp (c JSONB );
    
    sqltxt:='COPY tmp from '''||filepath||''' with (FORMAT TEXT, DELIMITER ''~'')';
```

Now in order to process this file sucessfully , I have to manually strip out the newline characters in the incoming file.

I would like to do this in my postgres code by using a function know as regexp_replace

I am struggling to do this

This is my attempt at this :

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
    CREATE TEMP  table tmp (c JSONB );

    -- Populate temp table with incoming JSON
    sqltxt:='COPY translate(tmp, E''\n,'', '''') from '''||filepath||''' with (FORMAT TEXT,     DELIMITER ''~'')';
    EXECUTE sqltxt;
```

this produceds the following code which when run produces the error:

```
COPY translate(tmp, E'\n,', '') from 'C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json' with (FORMAT TEXT, DELIMITER '~')

[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "E'\n,'"
```

How can I run this code to strip out all newline characters fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this through running a docker container

So I had to do the following:

1. Run up a Powershell command as Administrator.
2. Change folder to where the JSON files are stored eg : C:\ChrisDev\Readings
3. Run the following command to mount the folder into the Docker Container:
   docker run -it -v .:/files/ ubuntu
4. Now run the command to strip out Newline characters on the file

   sed -i -z -e 's/\r\n/ /g' '/files/926371_20230120.json'

Now here what im doing is /\r\n/ is replacing all occurances of Carriage Return (\r) and Line Feed (\n) with an empty space.

Once this is run, then i can run my JSON file through my program with not issues.

Answer (score 0):

-- Create a temporary table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp (c JSONB);

-- Populate the temporary table with incoming JSON, replacing newline characters
sqltxt := 'COPY translate(tmp, c) FROM ''' || filepath || ''' WITH (FORMAT TEXT)';
EXECUTE sqltxt;

-- Replace newline characters in the JSONB column using regexp_replace
UPDATE tmp
SET c = regexp_replace(c::TEXT, E'\n', '', 'g')::JSONB;

-- Now, your temporary table (tmp) contains JSON data with newline characters removed

Comment: I tried that but the following error message:

[2023-11-20 13:39:10] [42P01] ERROR: relation "translate" does not exist
[2023-11-20 13:39:10] Where: SQL statement "COPY translate(tmp, c) FROM 'C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json' WITH (FORMAT TEXT)"
[2023-11-20 13:39:10] PL/pgSQL function spsetchannelreading(text) line 17 at EXECUTE

Comment: this line fails  
-- Populate the temporary table with incoming JSON, replacing newline characters sqltxt := 'COPY translate(tmp, c) FROM ''' || filepath || ''' WITH (FORMAT TEXT)'; EXECUTE sqltxt;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in PostgreSQL. The only way to do something like that would be to call a program that modifies the file *before* you feed it to `COPY`:

```
COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM $$sed -z -e 's/\n/ /g' '/path/to/file'$$;
```

That example is for Linux. On other operating systems, you may need to call different programs.

Comment: I tried that using the following command 
COPY tmp FROM PROGRAM $$sed -z -e 's/\n/ /g' 'C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json'$$;

And then got the error message:

[2023-11-20 11:39:44] [38000] ERROR: program "sed -z -e 's/\n/ /g' 'C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json'" failed
[2023-11-20 11:39:44] Detail: child process exited with exit code 1

Comment: That won't work on Windows. Simply pre-process the file before you call `COPY`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the sed command failed to execute properly. The exit code 1 suggests that there might be an issue with the command syntax or the input file itself.

Here are some potential causes for this error:

1. Invalid Path:

   Ensure that the path to the file C:\ChrisDev\Readings\14.json is correct and accessible by the sed program.
2. Syntax Error:

   Double-check the syntax of the sed command for any typos or missing characters. The syntax you provided seems correct, but it's always good to double-check.
3. Invalid Input File:

   Verify that the file 14.json is a valid JSON file and doesn't contain any unexpected characters or formatting that might cause issues with the sed command.